# POST Form Data Without Submit

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have one form that contains many fields of data. There is a button on the form that will redirect you to another page to fill out additional information. Once you have finished filling out additional information you will navigate back to the original form. I'd like to be able to post the partially filled form , without actually submitting it, so I can store it in a session.

Is it possible to post form data without going through the action url specified on the form?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "post" and "submit". What exactly do you have and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click event to to your link or button (which takes the user to the second part of form/widget) and in that you can post the form using ajax to your action method and there you can save it.

Your js code should be something like this

```
$(function(){

  $("#idOfNextLinkOrButton").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var _form=$(this).closest("form");  //Get the form somehave

    $.post("@Url.Action("TempSave","Home")",_form.serialize(),function(result){
       //do something with the result
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: +1 but consider the behavior if Ajax is not available in the browser (JavaScript turned off).  Have a graceful user experience, even if it is just to show a page indicating that JavaScript is required.

Comment: @Shyju Wow that was actually pretty self explanatory. Should have figured that out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just post it to the same URL, but for example containing a hidden field `SurveyCompleted=false`, which you set to `true` when you are on the last page. Only when `true`, the input gets persisted, otherwise you just save it in your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can post to some other url using Javascript Ajax on click of some button/ submit form.

**Note:** Make sure when you click a button inside a form, the default behaviour is to submit, but you can prevent that.

in jQuery we do like

```
$('#btnSend').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('someurl',data,function(result){});
});
```

A data argument can be

```
data=$('#yourform').serialize(); // sends the whole form data

 or
data=JSON.stingify(someJavaScriptObject); // you can set and send anydata
```